# Linq select parent/parents record with matching child items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Using ef core and trying to select parent items according to criteria in the child item.

If I was doing this in sql I would

```
    declare @UserName nvarchar(200)
set @UserName = 'al65272'

declare @ClientId int
set @ClientId = 32

select u.*
from Users u 
inner join ClientUsers cu on u.Id = cu.UserId
where NormalizedUserName = upper(@UserName) and cu.ClientId=@ClientId
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
var userByUserName = _applicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.NormalizedUserName == userName.ToUpper() &&
                x.ClientUsers.Contains(new ClientUser {ClientId = client.Id, User = x}));
```

But obviously wrong as does not return anything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: In the provided SQL you address two tables  AspNetUsers and ClientUser  but in the LINQ you address Users. Could you edit your post with the proper data.

Comment: Sorry thanks. Corrected now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work for you :

```
var userByUserName = _applicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.NormalizedUserName == userName.ToUpper() &&
                x.ClientUsers.Any(c => c.ClientId == client.Id));
```